# Is there a power series that does not change in a closed domain of convergence after taking a derivative?

Tags: analysis, power-series

We know that the power series is infinitely differentiable in the radius of convergence, but after taking the derivative many times, the domain of convergence of the derivative may shrink, can we find such a power series whose interval of convergence is closed interval $[-R,R](R>0)$, and no matter how many times we take the derivative, the domain of convergence will not shrink?

Comment: I'm guessing you would also exclude the trivial case of the radius being $+\infty$? Just to clarify.

Comment: Err, this is false (ignoring the boundary which might change), the derivative has the same radius of convergence as the original function.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm looking for power series whose boundary doesn't change.

Comment: @Eric: The question was whether a series that converges iff $x \in [-R,R]$ can be such that all its derivatives also converge on $[-R,R]$ (rather than on $[-R,R)$ or $(-R,R]$ or $(-R,R)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that you want the coefficient to be less than $n^{-k}$ for all $k$ and greater than $ r^n$ for any $r<1$.

Some examples are:

$$\sum_n 2^{-n/\log n} x^n$$
and
$$\sum_n n^{-\log n} x^n$$
which have all of their derivatives converge on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Great! How do you find the conditions for the coefficients? That's amazing!

Comment: Latter is just from the radius of convergence formula. Former is because  you multiply by $n$ for each derivative, so being less than $n^{-k}$ is necessary for $k$ derivatives. If you’re less than $n^{-k-2}$ asymptotically, then by comparison with $1/n^2$, the kth derivative converges at 1.